Django FOREIGN KEY constraint failed when registering new users
I'm encountering a "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" error while trying to register new users in my Django application. Here's the relevant code from my models.py, serializers.py, and views.py files:
Serializers.py:
User = get_user_model()


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    friends = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'date', 'password', 'profile_picture', 'friends']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}

    def get_friends(self, obj):
        friends = obj.get_friends()  # Assuming get_friends returns a list of friend objects
        return friends if friends else []  # Return empty list if friends is empty

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("User Serializer create()")
        print("Validated data: ", validated_data)

        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        print("User before tokenization ", user.__dict__)
        print("User created, about to tokenize")

        # Check if user is saved in the database
        try:
            user_check = User.objects.get(email=user.email)
            print("User saved in database: ", user_check.__dict__)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            print("User not found in database")
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"error": "User not saved in database"})

        try:
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            if created:
                print("Token created: ", token.key)
            else:
                print("Token already exists for user: ", token.key)
            print("User and Token creation successful")

            # Ensuring transaction is committed
            transaction.on_commit(lambda: print("Transaction committed successfully"))
            return user
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error during token creation: ", str(e))
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"error": "Token creation failed"})

views.py
class UserView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            print("serializer is valid")
            try:
                user = serializer.save()

                token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
                print("Token retrieved: ", token.key)
                response_data = {
                    'token': token.key,
                    'user': UserSerializer(user).data  # Return user data if needed
                }
                return Response(data=response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error during response handling: ", str(e))
                return Response(data={'error': 'Internal Server Error'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        else:
            print("serializer is not valid")
            print(serializer.errors)
            return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

models.py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, name, email, password=None):
        print("User Manager create_user()")

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        if not name:
            raise ValueError('Users must have names')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        name = name.strip()
        user = self.model(name=name, email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        print("User before save: ", user.__dict__)  # Print user details before save
        user.save(using=self._db)
        print("User after save: ", user.__dict__)  # Print user details after save

        # Query the database for the user
        try:
            user_in_db = User.objects.get(email=email)
            print("User found in database: ", user_in_db.email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            print("User does not exist in database")

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/', null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_friends(self):
        return [friendship.friend for friendship in self.friend_set.all()]

    def get_followed_bars(self):
        return [follow.bar for follow in self.following_set.all()]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

Here is the debugging print statement output:
{'name': 'example user', 'email': 'example@user.com', 'password': 'password'}
serializer is valid
User Serializer create()
Validated data:  {'name': 'example user', 'email': 'example@user.com', 'password': 'password'}
User Manager create_user()
User before save:  {'\_state': \<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x000001D551313D10\>, 'id': None, 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$720000$3Meryh67k59Mt15lsIkNpP$tL/wSUPvGoCT00OUv04rO8FQI9OoO1gvgcU7qncRkgA=', 'last_login': None, 'name': 'example user', 'email': 'example@user.com', 'date': None, 'profile_picture': None, '\_password': 'password'}
User after save:  {'\_state': \<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x000001D551313D10\>, 'id': 1, 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$720000$3Meryh67k59Mt15lsIkNpP$tL/wSUPvGoCT00OUv04rO8FQI9OoO1gvgcU7qncRkgA=', 'last_login': None, 'name': 'example user', 'email': 'example@user.com', 'date': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 8, 19, 44, 45, 577140, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'profile_picture': \<ImageFieldFile: None\>, '\_password': None}
User found in database:  example@user.com
User before tokenization  {'\_state': \<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x000001D551313D10\>, 'id': 1, 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$720000$3Meryh67k59Mt15lsIkNpP$tL/wSUPvGoCT00OUv04rO8FQI9OoO1gvgcU7qncRkgA=', 'last_login': None, 'name': 'example user', 'email': 'example@user.com', 'date': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 8, 19, 44, 45, 577140, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'profile_picture': \<ImageFieldFile: None\>, '\_password': None}
User created, about to tokenize
User saved in database:  {'\_state': \<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x000001D5514A17C0\>, 'id': 1, 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$720000$3Meryh67k59Mt15lsIkNpP$tL/wSUPvGoCT00OUv04rO8FQI9OoO1gvgcU7qncRkgA=', 'last_login': None, 'name': 'example user', 'email': 'example@user.com', 'date': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 8, 19, 44, 45, 577140, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'profile_picture': ''}

Token created:  2b4b2cda5dc96d977eaee907b1f979c237335cf8
User and Token creation successful
Error during response handling:  FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Did you register your new User model into "settings.py"? It seems you didn't, because in your "serializers.py" you used "User = get_user_model()" and if you customize the "AbstractBaseUser", you must use your new User model, not the default one. Check  it out.
